# Not receiving unsubscribe presence or iq on login

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, unsubscribe

Me and another user are having both subscription and chatting, everything works fine if I am online. When another user will remove me from roster then I will receive following IQ and Presence based on which I am removing that user from my roster as well.

```
didReceive IQ ANOTHERUSER@MYSERVER

didReceivePresence 'unsubscribe' from ANOTHERUSER@MYSERVER

didReceive IQ none

didReceive IQ ANOTHERUSER@MYSERVER

didReceivePresence 'unsubscribed' from ANOTHERUSER@MYSERVER

didReceivePresence 'unavailable' from ANOTHERUSER@MYSERVER
```

But If I am offline and another user remove me from roster. I am not receiving presence or iq from that user when I will login again.So I am not getting notify in anyway. On openfire server in my roster it shows subsciption as none but I am not receiving anything.

Comment: One solution for this which I have implemented is, I will send one encoded message from other end whenever that user is removing me from roster. Presence and iq is not received but message get received when I am login again.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I would say that XMPP user receives any presence if that user is online. Correct me if I am wrong.

To point you one way I would tell you that there is one table named 'ofPresence' created by openfire if you are using openfire as xmpp server. There 'unavailable' presence is store which server sends when any user comes online. For online user 'offlinePresence' field is set as nil. I havent checked with unsubscribe, but you can check if that presence is stored in that database. If it is saving, there might be some way to get something.

Other way is to get roster list and check out missing Roster and remove that Roster.

Also as you mentioned in your comment, you can send an encoded message. That is an option but make sure you dont miss that message.

I implemented that via my application webservice since getting availability of users that have unsubscribed is not always proper.

Hope this helps. Its just my knowledge. Correct me if you get some thing.